# Returning the value of a +/- operator as a prefix with no actual value to add or subtract on a class object?

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading, operators

How would I be able to use a `+`/`-` operator on a class object when there is no actual value that I am adding or subtracting from?
I would assume that the actual value is 0 from a sample code:

```
x = 2.5
print(+x)
print(-x)
print(0-x)

>>> 2.5
>>> -2.5
>>> -2.5
```

However, when doing this on my class Interval on its `__add__` and `__radd__` method and trying to account for a nonexistent or 0? value, I get the TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'Interval'

```
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, mini, maxi):
        self.mini = mini
        self.maxi = maxi
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other,(int,float)):
            mini_sum = self.mini + other
            maxi_sum = self.maxi + other
            return Interval(mini_sum, maxi_sum)
        elif isinstance(other, Interval):
            mini_sum = self.mini + other.mini
            maxi_sum = self.maxi + other.maxi
            return Interval(mini_sum, maxi_sum)
        elif other == 0 or None:
            return Interval(self.mini, self.maxi)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Value to add must be an int, float, or Interval class object')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Interval(2.5,3.0)
    print(+x)


>>> TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'Interval'
```

My `__add__` and `__radd__` have the same code, so I've only included `__add__` to keep the post shorter.

Am I handling this with the wrong method? I assumed `+x` would use the `__add__` method, but perhaps I am wrong here?

Comment: `+x` would call the `__pos__` special method.

Comment: Ahh, there we go. I was wondering if there was a specific special method for just +x or -x, but just assumed it would use `__add__`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unary `+` and `-` operators use the `__pos__()` and `__neg__()` special methods.

(I wanted to give a better example than this but I'm being called away. This should illustrate the idea. Just like using `__add__()`, et al, you'd want to create and return a new object with the correct value)

As an example:

```
class Foo:
    def __neg__(self):
        return "I'm a negative Foo!"
    def __pos__(self):
        return "I'm a positive Foo!"

>>> f = Foo()
>>> +f
"I'm a positive Foo!"
>>> -f
"I'm a negative Foo!"
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. I was confusing `__pos__` and `__neg__` with `__add__` and `__sub__`. Thank you for the clarification in your example.